# What programs has the US implemented since 2008 to help education in Nigeria?

Tags: foreign-policy, education

I'm writing a research paper for a class on foreign assistance, and am focusing specifically on what the US has done to help education in Nigeria. Even more specifically, I'm looking at how what we've done has effected (or not effected) the literacy rate.

I'm working within a 2008-2014 time frame and am certainly not having trouble finding before and after statistics as well as overall figures spent, but damned if I can find any specifics on what programs were implemented more than a year ago.  USAID's website is incredibly unhelpful and as far as I can tell, ForeignAssistance.gov only reports on overall spending.  I'm going to keep looking, but if anyone can help me find both what programs have been implemented and possibly some performance evaluations of said programs, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Welcome to the world of philantropy and especially foreign aid, where the concept of efficacy and performance metrics is largely foreign (pun intended) :)

Answer (score 2):

Your research paper sounds interesting. I'll start with a side comment then try and answer your question or at least point you in the right direction.

One of the greatest challenges with conducting this kind of research in Nigeria (I'm Nigerian btw) is the lack of validated data. Most of the information and data is either outdated or inaccurate. Education is big in Nigeria both in the private and public sector as such it is heavily politicized further compounding data collection.

In answering your question, the US-Nigeria relationship (on education and other areas) tends to be highly collaborative so it won't be a case of what programs the US has implemented but rather what Nigerian education programs are supported by the US government. One such program is the Northern Education Initiative Plus (NEI+)